# Is the Norm of the Square Root of an Operator equal to the Square root of the Norm of the Operator

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have a positive operator $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, does it follow that 
$$\|A\|^{1/2} = \|A^{1/2}\|?$$

If not, is there some relation between these quantities?

Comment: Where did this peoblem come from?

Comment: A colleague of mine was using the polar decomposition of a operator $T = U |T|$ where $|T| = (T^* T)^{1/2}$. To help him solve the problem he used this fact. 

I suspect its false, but I am busy with homework so I do not wish to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use the fact that by the spectral theorem, the norm of a positive operator is its spectral radius.

Answer (score 2):

One can prove the equality by elementary means. Recall that $\lVert T^*T\rVert=\lVert TT^*\rVert=\lVert T\rVert^2$. Since the positive square root $\sqrt{T}$ is self-adjoint, it follows that
$$\lVert T\rVert
=\lVert \sqrt{T}\sqrt{T}\rVert
=\lVert \sqrt{T}\sqrt{T}^*\rVert
=\lVert \sqrt{T}\rVert^2.$$