# Semigroups: given $\|S_T f\| \leq C$, what can I say about $\|S_t f\|$ for $t \leq T$?

Tags: analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, semigroup-of-operators

Assume that we have a strongly continuous semigroup $(S_t)_{t \geq 0}$ of linear operator on a Banach $X$ such that for all $f \in X$,
$$\|S_T f\| \leq C \|f\|, $$
for some constant $C > 1$ and some fix $T > 0$. Can I deduce that for all $t \in (0,T)$,
$$ \|S_t f\| \leq C \|f\|  ? $$

Ok so I did some thinking and also found this post [Is the Norm of the Square Root of an Operator equal to the Square root of the Norm of the Operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176062/is-the-norm-of-the-square-root-of-an-operator-equal-to-the-square-root-of-the-no),
but I'm not sure that the spectral theorem applies with such general hypothesis. Can anyone confirm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(S(t))_{t \ge 0}$ is a $C_0$-semigroup in a Banach space $X$, then, there exist $M>1$ and $\omega \ge 0$ such that
$$\|S(t)\|\le M e^{\omega t}, \quad \text{ for all } t\ge 0.$$
In particular,
$$\|S(t)\|\le M e^{\omega T}, \quad \text{ for all } 0\le t\le T.$$
The constant $C=M e^{\omega T}>1$ is valid for $S(T)$ and also $S(t)$, $0\le t\le T$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up with. I even found some notes saying that I can estimate the $\omega$ from my constant $C$. Something like 
$$ \omega = \inf_{t > 0} \frac{\ln(\|S(t)\|)}{t} \leq \frac{ \ln(C)}{T} $$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. If $T : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is a bounded linear operator, then its operator norm is given by

$$ \|T\|
= \sup_{\substack{x \in \mathcal{H} \\ x \neq 0}} \frac{\|T x\|}{\|x\|}
= \sup_{\substack{x \in \mathcal{H} \\ x \neq 0}} \sqrt{\frac{\langle x, T^{\mathsf{T}}T x\rangle}{\langle x, x\rangle}}. $$

In the special case $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{R}^d$, then $\|T\|$ is the square root of the maximum eigenvalue of the positive semi-definite symmetric matrix $T^{\mathsf{T}}T$. Then your question can be rephrases as

> **Question.** If $(S_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a strongly continuous semi-group on a Banach space $X$, then is the map $t \mapsto \|S_t\|$ non-decreasing in $t$?

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}^3$ with $S_t = e^{tA}$, where

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Then using numerical computation, we find that

\begin{align*}
\| S_5 \|
&= \left\| \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 5 & -\frac{15}{2} \\
0 & 1 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \right\| = 97.9222\cdots
\end{align*}

while

\begin{align*}
\|S_7\|
&= \left\| \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 7 & -\frac{7}{2} \\
0 & 1 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \right\|
= 75.3107\cdots.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. Another question come to my mind: are semigroup of positive linear operators always monotonic?

Comment: I found an answer to my previous comment in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302144.pdf. 
I will let it here as I would say this is quite helpful (at least to me).

Comment: From your example it seems that I don't have $\|S_k^{\frac12}\| = \|S_k\|^{\frac12}$ for all $k \geq 0$. Can you explain which hypothesis of the spectral theorem does not apply ? Or is the answer given in the linked post wrong ?

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois, The semigroup $(S_t)$ appearing in my answer is not symmetric, much less positive. Recall that spectral theorem only concerns self-adjoint operators (or in general, normal operators).